# How do you explain the following equations geometrically?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

*Let D be the field in C, *$f=u+iv \in C^{1}(D)$*. Proof:*
$$\begin{vmatrix} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\newline
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \end{vmatrix}=\vert \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \vert^{2} - \vert \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} \vert^{2}.$$
*especially, when *$f \in H(D)$*, have*
$$\begin{vmatrix} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\newline
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \end{vmatrix}=\vert f^{'} \vert^{2}.$$
*The solution of the problem is easy, but what is the geometric meaning of these two equations?*
*The right-hand side of the equation is hard for me to handle.*